# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column: _data

Tags: android, settings, illegalargumentexception, ringtone, ringtonemanager

while running this code I am getting invalid: column _data exception

```
 RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                context,
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI)
```

basically I want to revert to system default ringtone from my application

Answer (score 0):

```
Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI
```

it will return current system ringtone
But if it is null then you may get invalid data column exception
so if you want to get current ringtone use this code

```
val currentToneUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
    requireContext(),
    RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE
)
val tone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(requireContext(), currentToneUri
```

)